# Code::Blocks compiler says TextFrame.h not found

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

When I try to compile my code, it says it fails because the compiler says "TextFrame.h : No such file or directory", however a text frame is created even with the error. I'm using Code::Blocks 20.03 as my IDE. Sorry if this is a very simple question, I'm new to wxWidgets. I'm also following a tutorial. This is the code currently:

main.h

```
#ifndef TEXTEDITORAPP_H
#define TEXTEDITORAPP_H

class TextEditorApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    /** Initialize the application */
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

DECLARE_APP(TextEditorApp)

#endif // TEXTEDITORAPP_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "wx/wxprec.h"

#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
        #include "wx/wx.h"
#endif

#include "main.h"
#include "TextFrame.h"

IMPLEMENT_APP(TextEditorApp)

bool TextEditorApp::OnInit()
{
        TextFrame *frame = new TextFrame(
                wxT("Simple Text Editor"), 100, 100, 400, 300);
        frame->Show(TRUE);
        SetTopWindow(frame);
        return true;
}
```

Edit: @Yunnosch wanted a minimal reproducible example:

```
#include "TextFrame.h"

IMPLEMENT_APP(TextEditorApp)

bool TextEditorApp::OnInit()
{
    TextFrame *frame = new TextFrame(
        wxT("Simple Text Editor"), 100, 100, 400, 300);
```

@Igor I'm on Linux, C::B used this command:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-static-3.0 -I/usr/local/include/wx-3.0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__WXGTK__ -pthread -Wall -g  -c /home/my-username/Desktop/C++/wxWidgets/texteditor/texteditorApp.cpp -o obj/Debug/texteditorApp.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/texteditor obj/Debug/GUIFrame.o obj/Debug/texteditorApp.o obj/Debug/texteditorMain.o  -L/usr/local/lib -pthread   /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.0.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2u_qa-3.0.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu_net-3.0.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2u_html-3.0.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu_xml-3.0.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu-3.0.a -lgthread-2.0 -pthread -lX11 -lSM -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lharfbuzz -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lpng -lexpat -lwxregexu-3.0 -lwxtiff-3.0 -lwxjpeg-3.0 -lz -ldl -lm
```

I used both an empty project and a wxWidgets template in C::B, both had the same error. With the empty project I attached the correct flags. I also reinstalled wxWidgets just to see if anything changes, but still same error.

Comment: If compilation failed, it could at most run and older exe, from the time when it did succeed. Did you do a clean + build and "frame is created" still stands?

Comment: @Yunnosch Sorry about the identical .h and .cpp files, edited it to display the correct files

Comment: @catalin It still displays that TextFrame.h is not found

Comment: @Wolf, I presume you are on Windows, you did build wxWidgets itself and can successfully compile and run `minimal` sample provided by the library. What is the command C::B generated to compile your code? Did you use a template to create your project or you started with the blank template and just updated it as needed?

Comment: Can you make a more [mre]? E.g. one with a .c which only contains `#include "TextFrame.h"`.

Comment: @Yunnosch I edited my original post with the replies

Comment: @Igor I edited my original post with the replies

Comment: @Wolf, are both cpp and h files in the same directory? Are you sure that the file is called `TestFrame.h`? Please post the result of `ls -la`

Comment: @Wolf, of course it does. Doing a "clean" will not magically make the header more visible. But if you do a clean, will you still be able to run the same (old?) executable after that?  Try adding `-I/Path/to/TextFrame_header` to the compile command

Comment: @catalin that worked! Thanks a lot!